# Mercurial ChangeSet In OSGi Bundle MANIFEST with Maven

Tags: maven, mercurial, osgi, maven-plugin, buildnumber-maven-plugin

I am trying to get the `Mercurial` `changeSet` and `changeSetDate` set in my `MANIFEST.MF` file of `OSGi` bundle using Maven.

I have added the `buldnumber-maven-plugin` into my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>hgchangeset</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <doCheck>false</doCheck>
        <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And my bundle plugin looks like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Build-Change-Set>${changeSet}</Build-Change-Set>
                <Build-Change-Set-Date>${changeSetDate}</Build-Change-Set-Date>
                <Build-Location>${basedir}</Build-Location>
                <Build-Machine>${env.COMPUTERNAME}</Build-Machine>
                <Build-Date>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Date>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
        <instructions>
            <!-- All imports, exports, etc... -->
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I am executing `install` goal I see that `Maven` outputs:

```
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.0:hgchangeset (default) @ esb-security ---
[INFO] Setting Mercurial Changeset: 6524595b0389+
[INFO] Setting Mercurial Changeset Date: 2012-09-05 11:38 +0100
```

But in my `MANIFEST.MF` I get:

```
Build-Change-Set: ${changeSet}
Build-Change-Set-Date: ${changeSetDate}
```

It does not include the values of change set and change set data. Maybe someone know where might be the problem?

Comment: Doesn't anybody know where might be the problem? I'm stuck on this. Please help.

Comment: Have you run this with debug output enabled? Does anything come up there?

Comment: No. I nothing related to the problem. I see that maven prints changeset and changeset date correctly but in final manifest I am getting: Build-Change-Set: ${changeSet}
Build-Change-Set-Date: ${changeSetDate}

Answer (score 0):

Unless maven-bundle-plugin explicitly supports expression variables like ${changeSet}, etc, they won't be resolved by Maven before this plugin execution. So, you may have to use a separate execution of manifest task bound before process-resources phase, and then use Maven's resource filtering support to post-process generated manifest and substitute those variables set by the maven-bundle-plugin.

Comment: Can you provide any example how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you change the phase for the hgchangeset goal to "initialize" it will occur prior to the Manifest file creation?

Alternatively you can create a stub MF file in your resources folder and use filtering to do the variable substitution, although felix should be able to do this for you.